# How to catch all errors by ErrorDocument

Tags: apache-2.2, errordocument

There is a possibility to set a error page using the ErrorDocument separately like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /site.html
ErrorDocument 404 /site.html
ErrorDocument 500 /site.html
```

But is there a way to catch all errors with on-line command at once? I’ve tried with empty string and with “*”, but it did’t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to my knowledge.  You have to create a separate ErrorDocument handler for each of the HTTP status codes you wish to have a custom page for.

See [Single ErrorDocument directive to catch all errors (.htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611748/single-errordocument-directive-to-catch-all-errors-htaccess) on StackOverflow and [Custom Error Responses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/custom-error.html) on Apache's documentation.

Comment: created an `.htaccess` to catch them all @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259452/1442789